# Модификаторы доступа класса в зависимости от ситуации

Tags: ооп, typescript

Есть ли какой-то способ указать, что определенный приватный метод или свойство публичен для определенных классов? Например:

```
class Parent {
    private [but public for Child] childrenContainer: HTMLElement; // сокрытый от всех, но видимый для дочерних
}

class Child {
    constructor(){
        parent.childrenContainer.appendChild( document.createElement('div') );
    }
}
```

Этого очень не хватает, когда внутренним (дочерним но не наследованным) экземплярам нужен доступ к приватному методу родителя. Без этой возможности приходится раскрывать многие приватные свойства и методы родителя, что совсем не нужно никому, кроме дочерних экземпляров, которые по смыслу являются частью реализации родителя.

Здесь в примере я привёл только одно свойство, его можно передать в дочерний класс и без раскрытия, но часто бывает так, что свойств очень много, и если их передавать, то будет много лишнего кода.

Comment: Несмотря на принятый ответ, буду рад видеть другие способы достижения данной цели, если они есть

Comment: www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes: [public-private-and-protected-modifiers](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#public-private-and-protected-modifiers)

Comment: и конечно же не забываем про [ecmascript-private-fields](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#ecmascript-private-fields)

Comment: @qwabra , поясните где в указанных вами документах описано что-то о том, как сделать приватное поле публичным для определенного класса или добиться похожего результата?

Comment: protected ............

Comment: protected видимый для наследников родительского класса, вопрос не об этом, в вопросе не происходит наследование.

Comment: Тогда геттер сеттер с хитрым дженериком

Comment: Или он публичен именно для класса с именем чайлд??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Typescript есть «[аварийный люк](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/19335)» для таких случаев. Можно получить доступ к приватному свойству при помощи квадратных скобок.

```
parent.childrenContainer // ошибка
parent['childrenContainer'] // ок
```

Впрочем на мой вкус, тут лучше бы подошёл метод родителя:

```
parent.addChild(document.createElement('div'))
```

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку. Только не уверен, что это не станет когда-то пофикшено или как-то изменено разработчиками ts. Насчёт вкуса - вечная проблема в ооп - какой объект главнее. Не всегда так просто можно решить, кому отдать право - родителю управлять дочерним, или чтобы дочерний управлял родителем. Например родитель может не знать всех нюансов вставки дочернего элемента.

Comment: Ну если придумают какой-то другой способ, то может быть. За три года не пофиксили.

Comment: Заметил минусы данного подхода - частично теряется проверка типов. Можно написать любой текст в кавычки, и он не вызывает ошибку. И не проверяет на отсутствие (не видит что тип может быть `smth | undefined`). Видимо это обычное поведение такой нотации.

Comment: Вроде вызывает. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAKYCcCmA7ALtA3gKGn6ADggJYBuYaS0wAFsSACbIoBc0AwnYwNoC60AXmh8A3NgC+2bKEgxO9Bllz5gAexQQ0CAK7A0qhAAoiZClQKJUaNvGZoAlEvwr1m6oMKX03AOS0FzD68Ys54wAB0BNoQNIZodBD2ItAA9CnQqgDWys4RUTGGACwATEmp6UgICAY5KuGUmoZladCV1Qi1ePHEEJFeaL4NaEHJLW01zpKSQA

Comment: Да, возможно в вебшторме какая-то недоработка или конфиг отличается. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Благодаря [этому ответу](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45244695/11929476) нашёл приемлемый вариант решения, при котором private становится как public для дочерних классов. Может кому-то пригодится для реализации различных списков и подобных структур. Публичный интерфейс родительского класса при таком подходе остаётся чистым, так как не приходится раскрывать его поля для дочерних классов.

```
class Parent {
    private childrenElements: Array<HTMLElement> = []; // Заметьте, что здесь private!

    constructor(){
      new Parent.Child(this);
    }

    private static Child = class Child {
      private parent: Parent;

      constructor( parent: Parent ){
        this.parent = parent;
      }

      childMethod(): void {
        // Но дочерний класс имеет доступ к родительскому private, как если бы он был public!
        this.parent.childrenElements.push( document.createElement('div') );
      }
    }
}
```

Такой подход работает потому, что считается, что дочерний класс находится внутри области родительского класса (в его скоупе). И при любом выносе наружу это перестанет работать.

Нюанс - класс Child здесь сделан статичным, чтобы после компиляции в JS он не создавался как свойство заново каждый раз внутри конструктора родителя.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?allowUnusedLabels=true#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-D1ENgXQ0dWQMpbrWsbfUw76QOhLkA

Comment: [Working as Intended](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17535) говорит он, ага, да-да. с namespace особенно

Comment: Дочерний класс должен быть внутри родителя, и если вынести, то он не работает. Неймспейс из вашего примера, насколько я понял из этого всего, не находится в скоупе класса (внутри его скобок)

Comment: 1)"Неймспейс ... не находится в скоупе класса" - совершенно верно, оно работает через скоуп, а не через принадлежность к классу - это побочный результат (баг) а не запланированная фича. наверное, всё сразу станет ясно если посмотреть на скомпилированный JS. но ктож туда заглядывает 2) неймспейс в моём примере это статические поля класса. доки: [declaration-merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) в частности [merging-namespaces-with-classes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#merging-namespaces-with-classes)

Comment: а теперь, возьмём `target: esNext` и "новый" private (`#`) https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?allowUnusedLabels=true&target=99#code/LYewJgrgNgpgBAFwExwN4Cg5bgYygQwGdC4BBNTbKgYkIQCc4BeOAcgAdGBlB1yqrDhAA7OvQg4EIegAoAlBQFK4wmAHcyAOgBCMhAAsAloTn8BAXzNVOhgG74E8Og8M4425rgLFFyqkNEGCSlZG3tHOHwALjIFDD8-AMIQWE0oEABzPSNCTXxNWgZTBOxLPzLSs0c6GPjlVQ1SM0tLIA

Comment: посмотрим - https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41773

Comment: пока что, предлагают использовать  флаг `useDefineForClassFields` в случае с `target: esNext`