# Доступность поля для любого класса внутри модуля

Tags: typescript

Ключевое слово `protected` делает поле класса доступным только для унаследованных классов. В некоторых языках оно, также, позволяет получить доступ к полю из любого класса, описанного в том же модуле. Что-то подобное есть в `TypeScript`?

Comment: Нет. Но с учётом того, что в JS вообще-то нет настоящего private/protected нет никакой большой сложности получить доступ к таким полям при желании.

Comment: @AlexeyTen это понятно, однако, такой подход желательно не использовать, если нет стандартных возможностей для решения вопроса.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/19335 относительно легальный способ, с сохранением типов. Никаких других стандартных способов нет.

Comment: @AlexeyTen спасибо.

Comment: @nup недавно я аналогичный вопрос задавал, но речь была про класс, а не модуль, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1207933/%d0%9c%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d0%bf%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%82-%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%83%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8

Comment: @nup, простое объявление переменной в модуле, без `export`